# replacing word in smarty but without touch links

Tags: php, smarty

I want to replace in article some word in smarty but without to touch links which contains that word:

After using this it replaces links too: `regex_replace:"/[wordtoreplace\r\t\n]/":" "`

**Update** **SOLUTION:**
escapes a href which contains "word"

```
regex_replace:"/<a.*>word(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|word/":" "
```

Comment: Character classes replace individual letters. So `[wordtoreplace\r\t\n]` says replace `w`, `o`, `r`, `d`, etc, the meta-characters are fine. You may try the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` if `smarty`s regex supports that.

Comment: How to use in this way: What_I_want_to_avoid(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|What_I_want_to_match

Comment: Rough example, https://regex101.com/r/iG3fT3/1.

Comment: Yes it works excludes a href links!!! Thanks
regex_replace:"/<a.*>word(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|word/":" "

Comment: How to combine with this regex: regex_replace:"/[\r\t\n]/":" "

Comment: Combine which part? The `|` is an or, the left part is ignored if found, the right part if found is replaced.